# How to hide output lines from console

Tags: java, api, console

```
static String EPM_ORACLE_INSTANCE = System.getProperty("EPM_ORACLE_INSTANCE");
static String HFM_CLUSTER = System.getProperty("HFM_CLUSTER");
static String HFM_APPLICATION = System.getProperty("HFM_APPLICATION");
```

This is a part of my code. It results in

```
oracle.epm.fm.domainobject.config.ConfigOM load
INFO: The path to the configuration file location is: E:\Hyperion\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epmsystem850/config/hfm/configom.properties.
May 19, 2021 5:40:48 AM oracle.epm.fm.domainobject.config.ConfigOM load
WARNING: The system could not find file E:\Hyperion\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epmsystem850/config/hfm/configom.properties; using default location instead: /oracle/epm/fm/domainobject/config/configom.properties.
```

I got my expected task run, but i want to hide the warning lines above. Is there a way to hide it from console window?

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
System.setProperty("java.util.logging.Level", Level);
```

to change the log log level, so here you could set the LEVEL to *SEVERE* or *OFF*. And according to the java docs in *java.util.logging.Level*

> The Level class defines a set of standard logging levels that can be
> used to control logging output. The logging Level objects are ordered
> and are specified by ordered integers. Enabling logging at a given
> level also enables logging at all higher levels.
> The levels in descending order are:
>
> SEVERE (highest value) >
> WARNING >
> INFO >
> CONFIG >
> FINE >
> FINER >
> FINEST (lowest value)
> In addition there is a level OFF that can be used to turn off
> logging, and a level ALL that can be used to enable logging of all
> messages.

Comment: That is right.
Eventually if you want to have better and more customized control over you logs, you can simply import log4j2 dependency and add a *log4j2.xml* (or json) to your classpath/resources, so from there you could specify different levels for different packages .